# Wildcards in "IF" Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, wildcard

I am trying to create a filter using a wildcard.  I have a string List of all Layers but I want to excluded certain ones "0", "Defpoints" and also any layers that end with -LT, -LT1, and so forth.

```
if ((ltr.Name != "0") && (ltr.Name.ToUpper() != "DEFPOINTS") && (ltr.Name != "*LT*"))
{
    AllLayerList.Add(ltr.Name);
}
```

Hope someone can help, thanks.

I just want these *LT* layers excluded from my list.  Could not find anything online that would help.

Comment: You forgot mandatory language's tag.

Comment: Wildcards dont work like that in C# string comparisons. you can do `!ltr.Contains("LT")` though

Comment: I need to mention that ltr is a LabelTableRecord and not a string list.

Comment: If is a string you can try `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`

Comment: Is your wildcard going to be `<anything>LT<anything>` or can it get more complex?

Comment: If you just need to know if the string contains `LT`, then you just need `ltr.Name.Contains("LT")`, otherwise you may need to use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@codeulike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22194/codeulike) mentioned [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050579/wildcards-in-if-statement#comment137598313_78050579), C# does not do those types of string comparisons in that way. With your example, you can use [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains):

```cs
if (ltr.Name != "0" && ltr.Name.ToUpper() != "DEFPOINTS" && !ltr.Name.Contains("LT"))
{
    AllLayerList.Add(ltr.Name);
}
```

If other cases may have "LT" in the name and should be included, then it may need to be changed to be more specific about the cases to exclude.

If "LT" can be lowercase, you can use `!ltr.Name.Contains("LT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead.

Comment: Worked they way I want it to. Thanks everyone.